Error in passing models between Spring MVC Controller and Javascript
In a Spring Boot project with Java 1.8 I'm having difficulty in correct communication between the controller which displays the values ​​correctly and the front-end part which doesn't seem to be able to receive them correctly.
I have the following endpoint in the controller:
    @GetMapping(value = {"/test"})
    public String test(Model model) {

        List<String> list = getFieldNamesExcluding(Arrays.asList("title", "type", "link", "referenceDates"));

        model.addAttribute("inputs", list);

        return "test";
    }

The content is a string representing an array of strings (e.g. “[hello,how,are,you]”)
The value of which I checked to be correct by debugging.
The html page to which the model is passed is:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" th:text="Press here" onclick="start()"></button>

<script th:inline="javascript">
    function start() {
        /*<![CDATA[*/
            var inputs= /*[[${inputs}]]*/ 'default';
            console.log("inputs: ",inputs);
        /*]]>*/
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>

But that way I get: message:  null.
I also tried receiving the value with JSON.parse() and using an hidden input: <input type=“hidden” id=“inputs” th:value=“${inputs}” /> but the result is a blank space.
PS: I'm using the 2.7.18 version of Spring Boot in the pom, to include Thymeleaf,

message: null? shouldn't it be inputs: null? The syntax looks ok, the issues looks to be somewhere else. In the pom, the dependency spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf should be enough to get you started.

Yes, forgive me, I wrote it by hand, actually it was 'inputs: null' and I have already the dependency you mentioned in the pom. Where could I look for the cause in your opinion, I've tried putting logs everywhere, but I can't figure out why the flow breaks like that?

@atish.s the most absurd thing is that trying to print the completed page:<script>     function start() {         /*<![CDATA[*/             var inputs = ["countries","inputTypes","tableNames"];             console.log("inputs: ",inputs);         /*]]>*/     } </script> but obviously inputs printed is null.. Now I'm trying to implement something that uses that field to understand if it's just a browser display problem or something else.

indeed a very weird behavior

I created a small test with the html being used and it seems there is an issue with the button tag which causes the thymeleaf processing to fail.
This th:text="Press here" is not a valid thymeleaf expression.
Use the following button tag and it should be fine.
<button type="button" onclick="start()">Press Here</button>


You're right, this is a little discouraging to me, though, because this was the extrapolation of logic that didn't work for me. However, if I reapply this logic to the source code it still doesn't work. I was hoping you'd tell me I had it all wrong so I could explain why it wasn't working, but if it was just this button (put in just for testing) that was the problem then I'm still bogged down.
